# Why prevent any setup method after the first request is called in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm working on a project with Flask and Flask-Restful, trying to get dynamic urls according to input from the user in my Restful API.  I created a class with a get method that will be responding to requests, and when the user calls upon another resource, it activates the new one and a url should be created.

The problem comes when I try to add a new resource to my api, which calls the function setupmethod in Flask that checks if the app is in debug and if the first request was already made.

```
 if self.debug and self._got_first_request:
     raise AssertionError('A setup function was called after the '
     'first request was handled. This usually indicates a bug '
     'in the application where a module was not imported '
     'and decorators or other functionality was called too late.\n'
     'To fix this make sure to import all your view modules, '
     'database models and everything related at a central place '
     'before the application starts serving requests.')
```

One simple way to overcome this would be to modify the add_view function in Flask to avoid this behaviour.  I first want to understand why would you avoid a setup method like creating a view or in my case a resource after the first request is called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is to avoid designs such as the one you just described. Define all your routes before hand. Then use the session or database to store whether a user has gone to one enpoint and is allowed to go to the next.

If you need routes with different parameters, then add a route with a `path` argument that can dispatch based on value, rather than dynamically adding new routes during runtime.

---

Another point, you should never modify the code of libraries you installed.  If you ever upgrade the library, your changes will get overwritten.  In Flask's case, you can subclass the `Flask` object and override this method instead.